# Differential equation containing a cross product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following problem from Apostol Vol 1 (14.9 #15):

> Given two fixed nonzero vectors $A$ and $B$ making an angle $\theta$ with each other, where $0 < \theta < \pi$, a motion with position vector $r(t)$ at time $t$ satisfies the differential equation $r'(t) = A \times r(t)$ and the initial condition $r(0) = B$.
>
> Prove that the speed (i.e. $||r'(t)||$) is constant and compute this speed in terms of $A$, $B$ and $\theta$.

So far I know that:

$$
||r'(t)|| = ||A \times r(t)|| = ||A|| \, ||r(t)|| \, \sin\theta
$$

but I am not sure how to make progress from there. If I could write it as $y' - P(x)y = 0$, I could plug it into the ODE formula and get an answer, but I don't think $A \times r(t)$ can be written as $P(t)r(t)$, and I think $||r'(t)|| \neq ||r(t)||'$, so $||r(t)||$ doesn't fit as $y$ and $y'$.

What's the right way to approach this?

Comment: Hint: take the dot product of both sides with $r(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $r'=A \times r$, we can take the dot product of both sides with $r$ to get
$$(|r|^2)'=r \cdot r'=r \cdot (A \times r)=0$$
The last part is zero because the cross product between 2 vectors is perpendicular to both vectors.

Comment: Is this proving that $||r'(t)||$ is constant, or $(||r(t)||)'$?

Comment: @PatrickCollins Let me add arrows at the top of vectors for clarity. After Paul's computation, that shows that $2 r(t) r'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}r^2(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}^2(t) = 2 \vec{r}'(t) \cdot \vec{r}(t) = 0$, you can compute $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{r}(t) = \vec{A} \cdot \left( \vec{B} + \int_0^t \vec{r}'(\tau) \mathrm{d} \tau \right) = A B \cos \theta$ and use both results to show that $\vec{r}'(t) \cdot \vec{r}'(t) = \left(\vec{A} \times \vec{r}(t)\right) \cdot \left(\vec{A} \times \vec{r}(t)\right) = A^2 r^2(t)-\left(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{r}(t) \right)^2 = A^2 B^2 \sin^2 (\theta)$.

Comment: @secavara Thanks! Should the last step be $||A||^2 \, ||B||^2 \cos^2 \theta$? By the $A \cdot r(t) = A B \cos \theta$ relation from above.

Comment: Sorry, just got back to this.  Thanks @secavara for filling this in!  Note that the last step uses the identity $1-cos^2 \theta=sin^2 \theta$.

Comment: Sorry, looking at this some more, I'm not sure I follow. At the end we have: $||r'(t)||^2 =  ||A||^2 ||r(t)||^2 - ||A||^2 ||B||^2 \cos^2 \theta$. We also have $(||r(t)||^2)' = 0$ but it doesn't seem to be used anywhere in the body of the proof, and I'm not sure how to resolve that $||r(t)||^2$ term in the $||r'(t)||^2$ expression. Am I missing the point?